# php output differs in firefox and komodo IDE

Tags: php, firefox, komodo

I installed komodo IDE 8.5 to write and test php codes. The first program I tried to test was this:

```
<?php   // test_1.php
     $username = "fred Smith";
     echo $username;
     echo "<br>";
     $current_user = $username;
     echo $current_user;

?>
```

when I run the program in Firefox it works as it should and prints fred smith 2 times in 2 seprate lines. but when I run it on komodo, the output is a

`fred Smith<br>fred Smith`

whats wrong whit program or IDE?

Comment: Change the `echo <br>` with `echo 'cli' === PHP_SAPI ? "\n" : '<br>';`

Comment: You never 'run the program in Firefox': it's always executed on server, and, as it stands, it always outputs the same string. But while IDE shows this output as is, Firefox treats the server's output as HTML file, hence `<br>` becomes a new line separator.